# Error when updating one field only Django Update method

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have a usecase model which has two foreign keys: kpi and usecase_type

I created a method to update those two fields from dropdown list,
The method only updates if I update all the fields (shows an error if update one dropdown list) , any idea what could be the reason?

My views.py:

```
def edit_usecase(request, ucid):
    try:
        usecase_details = Usecase.objects.filter(usecase_id=ucid)
        context = {"usecase_details":usecase_details[0], "usecase_types": UsecaseType.objects.all(), "usecase_kpis": Kpi.objects.all()}        

        if request.method == "POST":
            usecase_type = request.POST['usecase_type']
            kpi = request.POST['kpi']
            usecase_details = Usecase.objects.get(usecase_id=ucid)
            usecase_details.usecase_type_id=usecase_type
            usecase_details.kpi_id=kpi
            usecase_details.save()
            
            if usecase_details:
                messages.success(request, "Usecase Data was updated successfully!")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('usecase-details', args=[ucid]))
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Some Error was occurred!")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update-usecase', args=[ucid]))
        return render(request, 'UpdateUsecase.html', context)
    except:
        messages.error(request, "Some Error was occurred!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update-usecase', args=[ucid]))
```

my template:

```
<div class="row  d-flex">
    <div class="col-12 mb-4">
        <div class="card border-light shadow-sm components-section  d-flex ">
            <div class="card-body  d-flex ">
                <div class="row mb-4">                 
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row col-12">
                        <div class="mb-4">
                            <h4 class="h4 uc-header">Edit usecase details:</h4>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <li role="separator" class="dropdown-divider border-black mb-3 ml-3"></li> -->
                        <form action="/update-usecase/{{usecase_details.usecase_id}}" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-row mb-4">
                              <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
                                <label class="h6" for="project-name">Usecase Type:</label>
                                <select name="usecase_type" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="usecase_type">
                                    <option value="0" selected>{{usecase_details.usecase_type.usecase_type_name}}</option>
                                    {% for usecase_type in usecase_types %}
                                    <option value="{{ usecase_type.usecase_type_id }}">{{ usecase_type.usecase_type_name }}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}                             
                                  </select>                          
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
                                  <label class="h6" for="project-name">Usecase KPI:</label>
                                  <select name="kpi" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="kpi">
                                      <option value="0" selected>{{usecase_details.kpi.kpi_name}}</option>
                                      {% for kpi in usecase_kpis %}
                                      <option value="{{ kpi.kpi_id }}">{{ kpi.kpi_name }}</option>
                                      {% endfor %}                             
                                    </select>                          
                                  </div> 
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit Changes">
                          </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what goes wrong ? You stated that nothing happens when you don't update all fields. As i understand, you have only two fields. So you mean that nothing happens if you do not select a value for both dropdown list ? 
You also talked about an error. But you're using `try ... except` which is a really bad pattern. Try logging the error instead of silencing it `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it seems that, when nothing is selected for a dropdown list, you'll get "0" as a value.
There is probably no UseCaseType and no KPI of id 0 which means that django will throw an error as those are invalid values.
However you silence all error by encapsulating your code inside a `try except` which means that you did not see this issue in the console.

```py
usecase_details = Usecase.objects.get(usecase_id=ucid)
if usecase_type != "0":
    usecase_details.usecase_type_id=usecase_type
if kpi!= "0":
    usecase_details.kpi_id=kpi
usecase_details.save()
```

The above should solve the issue but you should consider removing your `try except` and selecting the option corresponding to the actual value instead of "0"

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided error logs. I think the problem with template select field selected value. You can try this code:

```
<div class="form-row mb-4">
    <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
        <label class="h6" for="project-name">Usecase Type:</label>
        <select name="usecase_type" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="usecase_type">
            {% for usecase_type in usecase_types %}
            <option value="{{ usecase_type.id }}" {% if usecase_details.usecase_type.id == usecase_type.id %}selected{% endif %}>{{ usecase_type.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}                             
        </select>                          
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
        <label class="h6" for="project-name">Usecase KPI:</label>
        <select name="kpi" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="kpi">
            {% for kpi in usecase_kpis %}
            <option value="{{ kpi.id }}" {% if usecase_details.kpi.id == kpi.id %}selected{% endif %}>{{ kpi.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}                             
        </select>                          
    </div> 
</div>
```